# Represent the following set of points in the XY plane

Tags: graphing-functions

Represent the following set of points in the XY plane:

{ (x,y) | |x|=1 }

{ (x,y) | |x| is less than or = 1 }

Comment: Where do you get stuck? Can you draw the set where $x = 1$ or $x = -1$?

Comment: yes its the answer for the first question right?

Comment: It is. Now for the second one, this also includes lines such as $x = 1/2$, $x = -1/3$ or more generally lines $x = a$ for every $a$ with $-1 \le a \le 1$. Can you draw it now?

Comment: for the second one, will the line start from -1 till 1 on the x axis

Comment: You may want to read about [why should we accept answers](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/why-should-we-accept-answers) and [how do we do that](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer/3287#3287). Your accept ratio is less than 40% which is less than acceptable on this site.

Comment: hey sorry i will remember this for the next time, actually i had not much information about that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Note that your set imposes no restriction at all on the $y$-coordinate. If you find a point in the set, every other point with the same $y$-coordinate will also be in the set. Now, what does $\{x\in\Bbb R:|x|\le 1\}$ look like as a subset of the real line?

**Added:** Your region is the blue stripe in the picture below; it extends infinitely far up and down.
[image]

Comment: for the second one, will the line start from -1 till 1 on the x axis

Comment: @meg_1997: That’s right, and it will include both endpoints, $-1$ and $1$. Thus, your region in the plane will be an infinite vertical stripe running between the lines $x=-1$ and $x=1$.

Comment: is it possible to show it on graph here by you

Comment: @meg_1997: I can produce a rough picture; hang on for a few minutes while I do it.

Comment: hey thanks for that:)

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Can you represent them on the $x$ axis?  Note that since the criteria do not depend on $y$ the sets will be vertical lines at all $x$ that are acceptable.